# How do receive stream from flask server (sent via yield) with axios (react frontend)

Tags: python, flask, axios, yield, yield-return

I'm sending the stream of data from flask server via yield. I'm able to see this stream if I go directly to api url. However I don't know how to receive it on frontend. I would appreciate the help. Here is how my backend looks like:

STREAM

`

```
def redis_stream():
    global lock
       channel = r.pubsub()
       channel.subscribe('CellGridMapClose')
       for msg in channel.listen():   
          if msg['type'] == 'message': 
                   obj = tm.CellGridMapping()
                   obj.ParseFromString(msg['data'])
                   objects = obj.objects
                   movement = []
                   for vehicle in objects:
                      x, y = vehicle.pos.x, vehicle.pos.y
                      movement.append({'posx': x/50, 'posy': y/40})
                   yield bytes(json.dumps(movement), 'utf-8')
```

`
ROUTE

`

```
@app.route('/redis-stream')
def redis_data():
   return Response(redis_stream(), mimetype='application/json')
```

`

This is how my frontend looks. I've tried many variants. This is the last one, however it's not working

FRONTEND

`

```
const response = await axios.get("/redis-stream", {responseType: 'arraybuffer'});;
    console.log(response.data);
```

`

Comment: Hi @Vladi Yudi, did you ever find a way to implement this?